# Json-schema required/non-required & allowed valeus for fields depend on the values of other fields

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have three fields, foo, bar, baz. bar depends on foo, baz depends on bar:

1. foo is bool
2. if foo is not provided bar & baz are forbidden
3. foo = true: bar is required enum with values bar1 & bar2
4. foo = false: bar & baz are forbidden
5. foo = true & bar = bar1: baz is a required object with required field baz1 and non-required field baz2 both string
6. foo = true & bar = bar2: baz is a required object with required field baz3 string

So I started building this iteratively. So far, I've got

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",  
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "not": {
          "required": ["foo"]
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "not": {
          "required": ["bar", "baz"]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "foo": {
            "const": true
          }
        },
        "required": ["foo"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "bar": {
            "enum": ["bar1", "bar2"]
          }
        },
        "required": ["bar"]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "foo": {
            "const": false
          }
        },
        "required": ["foo"]
      },
      "then": {
        "not": {
          "required": ["bar", "baz"]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "bar": {
            "const": "bar1"
          }
        },
        "required": ["bar"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "baz": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "baz1": { "type": "number" },
              "baz2": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["baz1", "baz2"],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        },
        "required": ["baz"]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "bar": {
            "const": "bar2"
          }
        },
        "required": ["bar"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "baz": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "baz3": { "type": "number" },
              "baz4": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["baz3", "baz4"],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        },
        "required": ["baz"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It correctly validates all combinations I've tried so far except when baz is present without foo & bar or with foo = false & no bar, which both validate to true even though I'd expect it to be false as both bar & baz are set as not require if foo is not required & if foo is false. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split up the `required` clauses so they check one keyword at a time.

`"required": ["bar", "baz"]` will be false if neither 'bar' nor 'baz' are present, which is what you want, but it will also be false if one property is present and the other is not, which is not (because you then wrap that check with a "not", making the "if" condition true).

Therefore, change that check to:

```
"allOf": [
  { "required": ["bar"] },
  { "required": ["baz"] }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ether's answer I've got this, it appears to be working as intended, so I'm providing it for ease of references for anybody who might need it in future:

```
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",  
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "not": {
          "required": ["foo"]
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "not": {
              "required": ["bar"]
            }
          },
          {
            "not": {
                "required": ["baz"]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "foo": {
            "const": true
          }
        },
        "required": ["foo"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "bar": {
            "enum": ["bar1", "bar2"]
          }
        },
        "required": ["bar"]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "foo": {
            "const": false
          }
        },
        "required": ["foo"]
      },
      "then": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "not": {
              "required": ["bar"]
            }
          },
          {
            "not": {
                "required": ["baz"]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "bar": {
            "const": "bar1"
          }
        },
        "required": ["bar"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "baz": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "baz1": { "type": "number" },
              "baz2": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["baz1", "baz2"],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        },
        "required": ["baz"]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "bar": {
            "const": "bar2"
          }
        },
        "required": ["bar"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "baz": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "baz3": { "type": "number" },
              "baz4": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["baz3", "baz4"],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        },
        "required": ["baz"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```